# iOS7 Sprite Kit how to reset/start new game with Sprite Kit?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, reset, sprite-kit, skscene

Up until now I've been working on a Sprite Kit game, with a new game starting every time I hit the "Play" button in xCode. Now I'm trying to implement a **"New Game" button** within the game which will reset the game and start a new one.

**What are the steps I need to take in order to ensure that my old game scenes are gone**, and don't have any dangling references?

- Do I need to do any kind of manual cleanup within a scene? (as in the old viewDidUnload) or will ARC take care of everything?
- Do I need to explicitly remove any view controller views that I might've added from within a scene to it's superview?
- Are there any built-in methods that can help me reset my game?

Here's what I was using until now.

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    //set the view only once, because this method will be called again on rotation
    if(!self.kkView.scene)
    {
        landscapeSize = self.kkView.bounds.size;

        self.kkView.showsFPS = NO;
        self.kkView.showsNodeCount = NO;
        self.kkView.showsDrawCount = NO;

        MyScene * gameScene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:landscapeSize];
        gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        IntroScene * scene = [IntroScene sceneWithSize:landscapeSize];
        scene.gameScene = gameScene;

        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        [self.kkView presentScene:scene];
    }
}
```

Comment: The best advice is to use Instruments to verify there aren't any leaks. The analyzer will also help, as will putting a log statement in a class' dealloc method. Everything else needs to be debugged with the code in question.

Answer (score 3):

ARC should take care of cleaning up object creation (like +sceneWithSize:). I also believe that if you're removing the entire SKScene that cleanup is done for all attached nodes and actions for you (possibly in the -willMoveFromView: method).

However, if you are looking to keep the scene and reset the nodes and actions inside the scene subclass itself, then you could do something like the following before the setup portion of your scene (either in the -didMoveToView: method or your own setup method):

```
[self removeAllChildren];
[self removeAllActions];
...
[self addChild:node];
etc
```

Comment: Thanks these lines of code helped me. But for some reason arc wasn't cleaning up everything(I'm using a beta XCode). So i used those remove methods before recalling the same SKSCENE and everything works now.